# How can I close thick hair tips made with curves while keeping their tubular form?

Tags: bezier-curves, hair

I wonder if there's a way to close thick hair tips made with curves while keeping their tubular form (not with pointy ends).

I'm using Blender 3.6.

Thanks in advance!

It would be nice if the hair tips look like the example in the image below:
[image: example]

Comment: Check Fill Caps in your Curve to Mesh node and set the resolution of your Curve Circle profile to 4. Then add a Subdivision Surface node to round off the tips of the hair.

Comment: Thank you so much for your quick reply! Unfortunately, adding the Curve to Mesh node is making the hair curves lose their thickness. There must be something I'm doing wrong.

I'll put my test file at this link if you want to check it out:
https://1drv.ms/u/s!Ar5iNc2c3ZKIgbpvG4yb400GNTKfUw?e=fFeuS1

Answer (score 1):

Here is how to set up your geometry nodes based on the file you shared:

[image]

You can go back to your second modifier : **Set Hair Curve Profile**
and play with the hair shape and radius.

Comment: I'm so thankful! This is exactly what I was looking for. Definitely, I have to keep learning about geometry nodes 

Comment: That's the spirit! Keep on blending ;)

Answer (score 0):

This may not be the exact answer you're looking for, but you can use <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>S</kbd> on each of your curve vertices to scale the profile of your bezier circle up and down, which means you shrink the bezier circle at the end of your path to narrow the end of the hair to a point. If you want more of a rounded end, just subdivide the the path of the curve near the end to slowly taper those curves.

Another way to do it would be to right click on your hair curves and go to Convert To > Mesh, then just Grid Fill each end and manually taper them how you want